# How to find the density function of the following?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with density
$$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x+1}{4},& -1\le x\le 1\\
\frac{3-x}{4},& 1<x\le 3\end{cases}$$ How to find the density of $|X|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The r.v. $\lvert X \rvert$ takes value in $[0,3]$. You can calculate the expression $\mathbb{P}(\lvert X \rvert \le x)$ explicitly by considering the two cases $0 \le x \le 1$ and $1 \le x \le 3$. For example for $x \le 1$ we get $\mathbb{P}(\vert X \vert \le x) = \int_{-x}^x f(y) dy$. Since $f$ is given, you can express this as $\int_0^x \tilde{f(y)} dy$. For $x \ge 1$ proceed in the exact same manner (just note that $\mathbb{P}(-x \le X \le -1) = 0$.

Comment: Please check my procedure: for $0\le x<1$, $\int_{-x}^x~f(y)dy=\int_{-x}^{-1}~0dy+\int_{-1}^x \frac{y+1}{4}dy$ and for $1\le x<3$ , $\int_{-x}^x~f(y)dy=\int_{-x}^{-1}~0dy+\int_{-1}^1 \frac{y+1}{4}dy+\int_1^x\frac{3-y}{4} dy.$ Am I correct?

Comment: That's correct. The first integral $\int_{-x}^{-1} 0 dy$ does not need to be there, as $-1 \le -x$, but that does not change the value anyway. You should also explicitly calculate the integral $\int_{-1}^0 f(y) dy$ and add it to the second integral, as a density $\tilde{f}$ should satisfy the relation $\mathbb{P}(\lvert X \rvert \le x) = \int_0^x \tilde{f}(y) dy$.

Comment: Please Check again: For $0\le x<1,~\int_{-x}^x~f(y)dy=\int_{-1}^x \frac{y+1}{4}dy=\frac{y^2+2y}{8}\big|_{-1}^x=\frac{x^2+2x-1+2}{8}=\frac{(x+1)^2} {8} $ and 

For $1\le x<3,~\int_{-x}^x~f(y)dy=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{y+1}{4}dy+\int_1^x\frac{3-y}{4} dy=\frac{y^2+2y}{8}\big|_{-1}^1+\frac{6y-y^2}{8}\big|_{1}^x=\frac{3+1}{8}+\frac{6x-x^2-6+1}{8}=\frac{6x-x^2-1}{8}$. Differentiating we get $f_{|X|}(x)=\begin{cases}
 \frac{x+1}{4}&~0\le x<1\\

\frac{3-x}{4}&~1\le x<3
\end{cases}$, which is not a density function as the integral value is not 1. Where is the mistake, I have committed?

Comment: The problem arises in the first step: If $x < 1$, then $-x > -1$, so $\mathbb{P}(\lvert X \rvert \le x) = \int_{-x}^x f(y) dy \neq \int_{-1}^x f(y) dy$. The second part $1 \le x < 3$ should be correct.

Comment: Okay will it be $0\le x<1,~\int_{-x}^x~f(y)dy=\int_{-x}^x \frac{y+1}{4}dy=\frac{y^2+2y}{8}\big|_{-x}^x=\frac{x^2+2x-x^2+2x}{8}=\frac{x}{2}$

Comment: Yes, that should be correct. Now you can differentiate as above to (formally) get the density of the distribution (as you did in the second to last post).

Comment: Is there any other approach to try this one?